# NetLogo - Sum lists of all turtles

Tags: netlogo

I am having trouble with summing lists of all turtles and am not sure where I am going wrong.

For instance, in the following code I would like to show the total number of apples among all the turtles. Every time I run the code I get a value of 0, when it should in theory be 100. I am not sure what the error is. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

```
turtles-own [ apples ] 

to test 
  clear-all 
  create-turtles 5 [ 
    set apples []
    set apples lput 20 apples
  ] 
  show sum [apples] of turtles 
end
```

Comment: Does the turtle variable `apples` have to be a list? In case an integer does the job, try `turtles-own [ apples ] 

to test 
  clear-all 
  
  create-turtles 5 [ 
    set apples 20
  ] 
  
  show sum [apples] of turtles
end` and the sum will be shown correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response @geruter. In this case, yes the variable does need to be a list. Even if each turtle list is populated with several items (all numbers), a value of 0 is still returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code and test should sum all the numbers in all the turtles' lists.

```
turtles-own [ apples ]

to test
  clear-all
  create-turtles 5 [
    set apples []
    set apples lput 20 apples
    set apples lput 10 apples
  ]
  ask one-of turtles [set apples lput 30 apples]
  show sum map sum [apples] of turtles  ; here's the key command
end
```

`map sum [apples] of turtles` sums the number in each turtle's list and puts those sums in a list, and then the first `sum` adds them all up.  I made one turtle's list longer than the others' just to be sure that all the lists do not need to be the same length.

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: Thank you @Charles for taking the time to help - that works beautifully!